# Backbone / Facebook API not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, facebook, backbone.js, facebook-javascript-sdk, marionette

In my index.html I call the Facebook SDK. In there I have the following code that triggers a controller in my Backbone application.

The trigger runs a function that calls the `FB.api()` that gets the logged in user.

The first example of backbone code works fine, but the second has a middle function that I pass the data to, but it gives me an error back from facebooks `all.js` file which is minified.

The reasons for wanting the middle function is to be able to fire them in different orders later on.

Facebook SDK:

```
FB.Event.subscribe("auth.statusChange", function (response) {
    MyApp.trigger("fb:initialize", response);
});
```

backbone.js controller code *WORKING*:

```
    initialize: function() {
        App.on("fb:initialize", this.getUser);
    },

    getUser: function(event) {
        if (event.status === "connected") {
            FB.api("/me", function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
```

backbone.js controller code *NOT WORKING*:

```
    initialize: function() {
        App.on("fb:initialize", this.testFunction);
    },

    testFunction: function(event) {
        var status = event.status;
        this.getUser(status);
    },

    getUser: function(status) {
        if (status === "connected") {
            FB.api("/me", function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
```

I have tried so far using what I think is called "closures".  As the FB.api() is asynchronous, `this` relates to the `window` instead of the current object. So I tried setting a variable to `this` outside the call.  But it also doesn't work.

For example:

```
        var oThis = this;
        var apiString = '/' + this.model.id + '/photos';
        FB.api(apiString, function(response){
            loadPhoto(response,  1, oThis.model);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  initialize: function() {
    var _this = this;
    App.on("fb:initialize", function(event) {
      _this.getUser(event.status);
    });
  },

  getUser: function(status) {
    if (status === "connected") {
      FB.api("/me", function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    } else {
      //do nothing
    }
  }
```

or alternatively use underscore's `.bind()` to always bind to the right this. http://underscorejs.org/#bind

Comment: Thanks for the reply, This also doesn't doesn't work.  And I was using underscores `_.bind()` but it also doesn't work.  Both give me an error in the `all.js`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use listenTo instead of App.on. Something like that:

```
this.listenTo(App, 'eventName', (function(_this) {
    return function() {
        return _this.getUser();
    };
})(this));
```